# Var_dump shows value but returns null mysql query

Tags: php, mysql

Using PHP and MYSQL I do a left join on 2 tables. I then use var_dump to show the results.

```
$sql = "SELECT pro_table.pro_id, pro_table.sport_id, pro_table.pro_name,
            results_table.pro_id, results_table.year, results_table.result_rank,                                    results_table.result_score 
    FROM pro_table
    LEFT JOIN results_table
    ON pro_table.pro_id=results_table.pro_id
     WHERE sport_id LIKE '$dropdownrecord'";



  $myData = mysql_query($sql,$con);
   while($record = mysql_fetch_array($myData)){
   var_dump($record);
```

this outputs

```
array (size=13)

  0 => string '276' (length=3)
  'pro_id' => null

  1 => string '14' (length=2)
  'sport_id' => string '14' (length=2)

  2 => string 'Bradley Wiggins' (length=15)
  'pro_name' => string 'Bradley Wiggins' (length=15)

  3 => null

  4 => null
  'year' => null

  5 => null
  'result_rank' => null

  6 => null
  'result_score' => null
```

I am not sure why my pro_id returns a 276 yet also says null?

Comment: what is in $sql? could you show your sql statement pls.

Comment: very confusing. what version of PHP do you use?

Comment: also array index '3' does not have column name. confusing...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My Problem was that I had both columns in both tables named the same think. I renamed one column and now it is working property.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this :

```
for($i=0;$record[$i] = $mysql_fetch_array($myData); $i++){
var_dump($record[$i]);
}
```